# Visual transformation for currency in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I would like to create a mask for TextField as `$ NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN`
Where is the issue in my code? How to do it better? It does not erease all of the characters

```
class CurrencyMaskTransformation : VisualTransformation {
    override fun filter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText = maskFilter(text)

    private fun maskFilter(text: AnnotatedString): TransformedText {
        // $ NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
        var out = ""
        for (i in text.text.indices) {
            if (i == 0) out += "$ "
            out += text.text[i]
        }

        val numberOffsetTranslator = object : OffsetMapping {
            override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
                if (offset <= 0) return offset
                if (offset <= 2) return offset + 1
                return text.text.length + 2
            }

            override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
                if (offset <= 0) return offset
                if (offset <= 2) return offset - 1
                return text.text.length
            }
        }

        return TransformedText(AnnotatedString(out), numberOffsetTranslator)
    }
}
```

EDIT:

```
val inputValue = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("100")) }

            TextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentWidth()
                    .height(64.dp),
                value = inputValue.value,
                onValueChange = {
                    inputValue.value = it
                },
                visualTransformation = CurrencyMaskTransformation()
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pattern is `$ NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN` you should use as `OffsetMapping` something like;

```
    val numberOffsetTranslator = object : OffsetMapping {
        override fun originalToTransformed(offset: Int): Int {
            if (offset <= 0) return offset
            return text.text.length + 2
        }

        override fun transformedToOriginal(offset: Int): Int {
            if (offset <= 2) return offset
            return offset -2
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure how you did it that $ sign is removed as well. This offset mapping is not working for me

Comment: @MasterDisaster post also the code the the TextField

Comment: @{Gabriele Mariotti} added textfield to question

Comment: @MasterDisaster Sorry my bad. I've updated the answer. In the `transformedToOriginal` you have to consider the `offset` instead of `text.text.length`